# matlab GUI callback

Tags: function, matlab, user-interface, callback, fft

I have this function in an m-file and I want to make a callback for push button but I have no clue how. Can anyone help me?
This is the function:

```
function f=fftreal(f,N,dim);
error(nargchk(1,3,nargin));

if nargin<3
  dim=[];  
end;

if nargin<2
  N=[];
end;

if ~isreal(f)
  error('Input signal must be real.');
end;


[f,N,Ls,W,dim,permutedsize,order]=assert_sigreshape_pre(f,N,dim,'FFTREAL');

N2=floor(N/2)+1;

f=comp_fftreal(f);

permutedsize(1)=N2;

f=assert_sigreshape_post(f,dim,permutedsize,order);
end
```

This is the user interface code that the GUI automatically generated:

```
function varargout = Fourier_Transform_GUI(varargin)
%FOURIER_TRANSFORM_GUI M-file for Fourier_Transform_GUI.fig
%      FOURIER_TRANSFORM_GUI, by itself, creates a new FOURIER_TRANSFORM_GUI or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = FOURIER_TRANSFORM_GUI returns the handle to a new FOURIER_TRANSFORM_GUI or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      FOURIER_TRANSFORM_GUI('Property','Value',...) creates a new FOURIER_TRANSFORM_GUI using the
%      given property value pairs. Unrecognized properties are passed via
%      varargin to Fourier_Transform_GUI_OpeningFcn.  This calling syntax produces a
%      warning when there is an existing singleton*.
%
%      FOURIER_TRANSFORM_GUI('CALLBACK') and FOURIER_TRANSFORM_GUI('CALLBACK',hObject,...) call the
%      local function named CALLBACK in FOURIER_TRANSFORM_GUI.M with the given input
%      arguments.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help Fourier_Transform_GUI

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 05-Dec-2012 15:46:34

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @Fourier_Transform_GUI_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @Fourier_Transform_GUI_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [], ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
   gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before Fourier_Transform_GUI is made visible.
function Fourier_Transform_GUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   unrecognized PropertyName/PropertyValue pairs from the
%            command line (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for Fourier_Transform_GUI
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes Fourier_Transform_GUI wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = Fourier_Transform_GUI_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in exit.
function exit_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to exit (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on button press in FFT.
function FFT_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to FFT (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on button press in iFFT.
function iFFT_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to iFFT (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on button press in DFT.
function DFT_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to DFT (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on button press in iDFT.
function iDFT_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to iDFT (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on button press in load_file.
function load_file_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to load_file (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
```

Comment: Constantinos, do you have some user interface code already? If so, please share it.

Comment: I put the code in the question if it's not understandable please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see in the generated code:

```
    % --- Executes on button press in FFT.
function FFT_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to FFT (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles

    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

%pre-processing
f=fftreal(f,N,dim);
% post-processing
```

This is the part of the code that will execute after FFT button press...

So do a call to your own function here and you should be done.